# Modify variable of textview

Tags: android

```
int triesno=5;
final TextView tries= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tries);
tries.setText("you have "+triesno.toString()+" tries left");
```

I want to make a game that when the user sends wrong input he gets less tries. The above code prints the initial number, but I want to modify only the variable and not to update like:

```
triesno--;
tries.setText("you have "+triesno.toString()+" tries left");
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Clear what you asking about?

Comment: I don't want to write the text, I want to modify only the variable.

Comment: Modify whay variable?

Comment: tries.toString() I want to update only that part of the textview, and not the whole text.

Comment: He has two variables with same name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int tries = 5;
    final TextView triesTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tries);
    tries = tries - 1;
    String triesStr = String.format("you have: %d tries left", tries);
    triesTv.setText(triesStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about your question?

```
final TextView tvTries = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tries);
int tries = Integer.parseInt(tvTries.getText()); // Get current number of time that you can try to.
tvTries .setText("you have "+ --tries + " tries left"); // -1 and set to textview
```

Comment: well initially, the textview will be set tries.setText("you have "+triesno.toString()+" tries left"); I was asking if there is a way to not write tries.setText("you have "--triesno+" tries left"); again later.